# Questions with long titles and no spaces in it show the scroll bars when displayed on the realtime questions page

Tags: feature-request, bug, scrolling, realtime-questions

When there is a long title, you have to scroll to see it:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I realise there isn't much of a solution, but it really breaks up the view of the page - so could overflow be hidden on these posts?

Comment: Why don't you just edit the title?

Comment: @DavidPostill well in the case that made me notice it I don't have editing privs and it looked like that for a reason.

Comment: Hmm. What is the URL?

Comment: @DavidPostill http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776445/command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcodedefault-xctoo?s=25|0.0000

Comment: Ah, what? You're not nicael, then? Okay. My name it Tim! ;)

Comment: @tim fixed ... ;)

Comment: Okay, I got it. The titles that contain paths can easily get such a long "words".

Comment: @DavidPostill it comes down to a concept of planned endeavor and fulfillment. Some users just say "I want to go look at a bunch of stuff" and then happily drill into what's there in whatever capacity is needed. Others say "I really want to get that badge that damn site has been teasing me with" and if something is getting in their way, it's worth considering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We should be rejecting these titles with guidance.

> It's fine to post the error you received, but the error belongs in your **question**, after you describe what led to it. A better title for your question is stating what you wish to accomplish.

Gotta run some numbers to grok a good number of characters before a space *should* probably appear, and look at what would hit it erroneously, but this is something we probably want to reject (or immediately send to triage).

Comment: That seems sensible. I can't think of a high quality question that would need no spaces in that way... I was surprised that one had +17.

Comment: You could use the char count from the longest English word. Even some sites using long scientific and medical words shouldn't be too long that a space *after* would stop the scroll bar appearing - e.g. pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis is only 45 chars. And people would have to use "Titin" not it's full chemical name :D

Comment: @James Someone on http://travel.stackexchange.com/ might wish to use Llanfair­pwllgwyngyll­gogery­chwyrn­drobwll­llan­tysilio­gogo­goch (58 letters) or Taumatawhakatangihangakoauauotamateaturipukakapikimaungahoronukupokaiwhenuakitanatahu (85 letters)

Comment: @DavidPostill Good point, but I think it's fair if they used  "Gogogoch" and "Taumata" :) Interestingly, [Google's search results](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=Taumatawhakatangihangakoauauotamateaturipukakapikimaungahoronukupokaiwhenuakitan%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Batahu) for Wikipedia's page for "Taumata" (when searching full length) is "Untitled".

Comment: @james The official abbreviations are Llanfairpwll or Llanfair PG - and by the way I've visited both  Llanfair PG and Taumata ;)

Comment: @Tim Did you decide anything here? Are super long words now blocked?